# STS site definition different "default.aspx" - (default document in site collection) (Solved)

Tags: site-template, asp.net, default-document

I have an STS-based site collection and I have changed the "default.aspx" default document reference as follows:

My onet.xml:

```
<Module Name="Default" Url="" Path="">
      <File Url="etusivu.aspx" NavBarHome="True">
```

This way the site works when I use the URL `http://SITEURL/etusivu.aspx`
but if I use `http://SITEURL/` it doesn't redirect to etusivu.aspx.
Even if I change "default document" in IIS to be "etusivu.aspx" in the correct webapp it doesn't work either.

Is there any possible way to correct this redirect?

Using SPS based site definition works but....

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved problem.**

I provisioned new "default.aspx" which was my old and correct etusivu.aspx (chosted the file) with a feature to site collections /root.

No features need to activate for this. Just make feature which provisions the file to the root of site collection and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the Welcome Page for the site.  This can be done either in your ONET.XML under `<WebFeatures> <Properties>`:

```
<Property Key="WelcomePageUrl" Value="$Resources:cmscore,List_Pages_UrlName;/etusivu.aspx"/>
```

or manually in Site Settings, Look and Feel:

`<siteurl>/_layouts/AreaWelcomePage.aspx`

Comment: You have to have publishing features enabled in site collection...

Comment: Sorry, that was implied. Good comment though. :)  So the full snippet would be:
<WebFeatures>
 <!-- Publishing feature -->
 <Feature ID="22A9EF51-737B-4ff2-9346-694633FE4416">
 <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <Property Key="WelcomePageUrl" Value="$Resources:cmscore,List_Pages_UrlName;/Default.aspx" />
 <Property Key="SimplePublishing" Value="true" />
 </Properties>
</Feature>